# insert images in a div after a specific img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am uploading images using ajax. But after ajax response I am trying to display the images in a div from that response. I am facing issue to append image after a specific img tag or at the end of the last img tag.

Comment: please show your code , that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'abc.xyz',
       //more options here,
       success:function(data){  /
          //logic to append data after last image
           $(data).appendAfter("img:last");   // assuming data as html 
       }
    })
})
```